# Twig/Symfony "markdown_to_html" filter not found for **debug:translation**

Tags: symfony, console, twig, translation

This error shows even in absence of any template and translation files.

**Symfony 4.4.0 (env: dev, debug: true)**

No other debug command fails this way, so this error must be template related.

And actually **NO FILTER** is found.

Why?

```
website@2ec9200e4614:~$ console -vvvv debug:transl en

In content_markdown.html.twig line 1:

  [Twig\Error\SyntaxError]            
  Unknown "markdown_to_html" filter.  

Exception trace:
  at /var/lib/website/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Email/zurb_2/notification/content_markdown.html.twig:1
 ...
 Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Translation\TwigExtractor->extractTemplate() at /var/lib/website/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Translation/TwigExtractor.php:59
 ...
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/lib/website/bin/console:39

debug:translation [--domain [DOMAIN]] [--only-missing] [--only-unused] [--all] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <locale> [<bundle>]
```

Comment: so is this an untouched symfony installation (highly doubt that)? if not, what did you change?

Comment: No, I have new services, some plugins etc. My problem here is that I can't find which one of those causes this error without removing averything and adding again step by step. And SO really doesn't let me paste a lot of code unless I also enter pointless description.

Comment: then use some external site like pastebin or whatever.  but tbh if you have a strategy to find out, maybe you should use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Symfony 4.4.0 and 5.0 which I have just now encountered as well; see my issue report for further context:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34618

[EDIT] The older issue on this matter here, as the earlier one was a dupe.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34586

You can work around this by adding the necessary optional Twig filters and bundle to your project, as so:
`composer require twig/extra-bundle twig/markdown-extra twig/inky-extra twig/cssinliner-extra`

I am not sure why this received immediate downvotes, but maybe including your Symfony version in the title or body would be helpful next time. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.

Before asking here I asked G, nada. Installed **twig/markdown-extra**, didn't work, didn't have time to investigate further.